# Get the same result when joining different column that has multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to sum table A and get the names of the people belonging to their personID, but when I do that I get a whole different result. I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to correct it.

```
SELECT PERSONID, SUM(DEBIT)
FROM TABEL A
GROUP BY PERSON ID
```

I get the following as result. This is a correct.

[image: q]

[image]

But when I join table B I get a higher debit amount.

```
SELECT A.PERSONID, SUM(A.DEBIT), B.NAME_FAM_MEMBER, B,NAME_DECEASED FROM TABELA A
JOIN TABLEB B
ON B.PERSONID = A.PERSONID
GROUP BY A.PERSONID,  B.NAME_FAM_MEMBER, B,NAME_DECEASED
```

I only want a single name of the a person belonging to the personID without it effecting the amount.

[image]

Comment: The `PersonID` is duplicated in the second table.  You need to figure out which row you want.

Comment: In future please show your data as formatted text, not images.Or for bonus points DDL/DML statements setting up some sample data.

Comment: Normally we would take the spouse or widow, but there are cases were there is only child. So it's hard to make a choice based of that.

Alright, i'll try to use text format next time

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can show up all of the three records in Personid, if you need to show just one, you have to define "rules" that going to say which is your preferences.

Eg:

```
with sum_data
  as (
 select PERSONID
       , SUM(DEBIT) as tot_sum
   from TABLEA
 group by PERSON ID
      )
select b.
  from sum_data sd
  join TABLEB b
    on sd.personid=b.personid
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Thank you mucho. 
What do i need to add if i only want to show one record?
For my issue, i just took the results placed them in excel and removed the duplicate rows on PERSONID